# Help with transition between rooms using hardwood and laminate flooring

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, laminate-floor, transition

All hardwood and laminate flooring needs an expansion gap according to every manufacturer.

My problem is that I am replacing carpeting in one room that connects to my entryway area.  The new floor will be laminate that will be the same height as the existing hardwood floor in the entry.  Now, the usual recommendation would be to use T-molding but since the room has a 71" opening (obviously no door here) I would prefer it be more seamless.

I've seen many, many examples of transitions between flooring that do not have a t-molding and are flush. So, how can I accomplish this?  Am I okay with an expansion gap on the opposite end of the laminate flooring while keeping the laminate/hardwood flush?

[image: Flush transition]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d try keeping them flush, you’ll have expansion allowance on both floors anyway. Just think of it as one floor with expansion gap around the perimeter.  Which it will be effectively